# What is the name of the method or process when a system is evaluated against the highest degree terms?

Tags: polynomials, probability-limit-theorems

I have noticed this method applied in the economics, statistics, and computer science. Where a system of expressions is being evaluated, normally a set of polynomials. During an evaluation, only the highest degree terms are used. I understand this is because when dealing with sufficiently large inputs the subsequent terms effects on the system are trivial.
(I don't want to say it is only used in polynomial systems because I am not 100% sure??)

Ideal outcome from this inquiry:
1. Identification of this system, process or method

2. Sources to read more on the application of this method as well as academic instances, applied instances.
3. Historical reference to when this was first applied, associate theorem. 
   Barring that, some historical or highly influential applications of this practice.
4. Is this the best online community to ask questions of this nature?
5. Is there an online resource that I should be aware of so as to not waste the time of the community in the future. Any online or text encyclopedia of theorems, processes, and proofs?

Though, I don't ask many questions because the answer is normally available with some digging and I don't want to waste the communities time. But, when I do post a question I get to say thank you. So, a thousand times, thank you very much.

Comment: Big O Notation is commonly used

Comment: Is that true in the disciplines of statistics and economics as well? Or by pulling at that string will I be able to find the discipline equivalent process?

Comment: I imagine it has applications in many fields which entail the use of mathematical approximations